# $_Post request and refresh

Tags: php, post

I have problem with my Menu application. It should allow to make order ( drink or dinner) and chose from few options. ( I have to do it without database or any external files thats why my code is in 1 file and includes css - sory for that)
Unfortunately when i fill my table $order with something  right after its filled it gets empty. I know its connected with working _Post but i have no idea how to dodge this. Any ideas?

```
<?php
$order[10] = new Dish;
$i=0;
class Dish
{
    private $Price;
    private $Name;
    public function setData($Price, $Name)
    {
        $this->Price = $Price;
        $this->Name = $Name;
    }

    function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->Price;
    }

    function getName()
    {
        return $this->Name;
    }
}
$Polish_Dinner = new Dish;
$Polish_Dinner->setData("3$", "Kapusniak");
$Polish_Desser = new Dish;
$Polish_Desser->setData("3$", "Kapusniak z cukrem");


$Mexican_Dinner = new Dish;
$Mexican_Dinner->setData("4$", "Fasola");
$Mexican_Desser = new Dish;
$Mexican_Desser->setData("4$", "Fasola z cukrem");

$Italy_Dinner = new Dish;
$Italy_Dinner->setData("5$", "Pizza");
$Italy_Desser = new Dish;
$Italy_Desser->setData("5$", "Pizza z cukrem");

$Ice = new Dish;
$Ice->setData("0.5$", "Ice");

$Lemon = new Dish;
$Lemon->setData("0.5$", "Lemon");

$Drink = new Dish;
$Drink ->setData("20$","Just Drink");
?>
<div style="background-color: gray;">

<form action ="index.php" method="post">
            <input type="submit" value="Dinner" name="Dinner" style="margin: 35px 100px; display: inline;  ;width: 20%; height: 300px" />
            <input type="submit" value="Cash" name="Cash" style="display: inline;  width: 10%; height: 75px" />
            <input type="submit" value="Name" name="Name" style="display: inline;  width: 10%; height: 75px" />
            <input type="submit" value="Drink" name="Drink" style="margin: 35px 0 0 100px   ; display: inline; width: 20%; height: 300px"/></br>
</form>
</br></br></br>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Dinner']))
{
    ?>
    <form action ="index.php" method="post" style=" background-color: darkgreen;">
        <input type="submit" value="Mexican" name="Mexican" style="margin-left:100px; display: inline; width: 20%; height: 100px" />
        <input type="submit" value="Polish" name="Polish" style="margin-left:100px;display: inline;  width: 20%; height: 100px" />
        <input type="submit" value="Italy" name="Italy" style="margin-left: 100px; display: inline;   width: 20%; height: 100px"/></br>
    </form>
<?php
}
elseif(isset($_POST['Drink'])) 
{
    $order[$i]=$Drink;
    $i++;
?>
    <form action ="index.php" method="post" style="background-color: darkgreen;">
        <input type="submit" value="Extra ice" name="ice" style="margin-left: 100px; display: inline;width: 20%; height: 100px" />
        <input type="submit" value="Extra lemon" name="lemon" style="margin-left: 100px; display: inline;width: 20%; height: 100px" />
        <input type="submit" value="Extra Ice + Lemon" name="iclem" style="margin-left: 100px; display: inline;width: 20%; height: 100px" />
    </form>
<?php
}

if(isset($_POST['Mexican'])) {
    ?>
    <form action ="index.php" method="post" style="background-color: darkblue;">
        <input type="submit" value="Mexican Lunch" name="Mex_Lunch" style="margin-left: 100px; display: inline;width: 20%; height: 100px" />
        <input type="submit" value="Mexican Lunch + Desser" name="Mex_Desser" style="margin-left: 100px; display: inline;width: 20%; height: 100px" />
    </form>
    <?php
} else if(isset($_POST['Polish'])) {
     ?>
    <form action ="index.php" method="post" style="background-color: darkblue;">
        <input type="submit" value="Polish Lunch" name="Pol_Lunch" style="margin-left: 100px; display: inline;width: 20%; height: 100px" />
        <input type="submit" value="Polish Lunch + Desser" name="Pol_Desser" style="margin-left: 100px; display: inline;width:20%; height: 100px" />
    </form>
    <?php
} else if(isset($_POST['Italy'])) {
    ?>
    <form action ="index.php" method="post" style="background-color: darkblue;">
        <input type="submit" value="Italy Lunch" name="It_Lunch" style="margin-left: 100px; display: inline;width: 20%; height: 100px" />
        <input type="submit" value="Italy Lunch + Desser" name="It_Desser" style="margin-left: 100px; display: inline;width: 20%; height: 100px" />
    </form>
    <?php
} else if(isset($_POST['Mex_Desser'])) {
    $order[$i]=$Mexican_Desser;
    $i++;
    $order[$i]=$Mexican_Dinner;
    $i++;
} else if(isset($_POST['Mex_Lunch'])) {
    $order[$i]=$Mexican_Dinner;
    $i++;
} else if(isset($_POST['Pol_Desser'])) {
    $order[$i]=$Polish_Desser;
    $i++;
    $order[$i]=$Polish_Dinner;
    $i++;
} else if(isset($_POST['Pol_Lunch'])) {
    $order[$i]=$Polish_Dinner;
    $i++;
} else if(isset($_POST['It_Desser'])) {
    $order[$i]=$Italy_Desser;
    $i++;
    $order[$i]=$Italy_Dinner;
    $i++;
} else if(isset($_POST['It_Lunch'])) {
    $order[$i]=$Italy_Dinner;
    $i++;
}else if(isset($_POST['Ice'])) {
    $order[$i]=$Ice;
    $i++;
}else if(isset($_POST['Lemon'])) {
    $order[$i]=$Lemon;
    $i++;
}
else if(isset($_POST['iclem'])) {
    $order[$i]=$Lemon;
    $i++;
    $order[$i]=$Ice;
    $i++;
}
if(isset($_POST['Cash'])) {
    if($i==0)
        echo("Make your order first!");
    else
        echo $order[$i]->getPrice();
}
if(isset($_POST['Name'])) {
    if($i==0)
        echo("Make your order first!");
    else
        echo $order[$i]->getName();
}
?>

</div>
```

..........

Comment: you want the inputs repopulated with submitted data, after the form has been sent?

Comment: I want to keep results in $order. When you press Dinner, Polish,Din + des
I want to save in my table order[0]->Poli_Dinner order[1]->Polish_des later i want you to press drink and extra lemon and i want to keep
order[0]->Poli_dinner order[1]->Polish_des order[3]->drink order[4]->lemon 

What do you think? Is it possible to do it this way?

Comment: every post is a new request so old variables are lost by default - you need to store the variables(previous sections) in either hidden form fields or sessions.

Comment: Its something absolutly new for me, but thanks - I'll try to google it and find  answer.

Comment: alternatively, get funky with js. and the data will be posted once only at the end of the selection process

Comment: Just curious, why are you limited to only 1 file and nothing else? From what I can read, you're basically resetting it every time that you're submitting/refreshing it. There are many ways you could easily (more easily) go about doing this system. Is it limited resources or limited knowledge? If it's limited knowledge, I'm sure we'll gladly help.

Comment: My resources are limited by the task I've been given. Its not my decision :<<

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compound your order results into an array, you have to assign the variable a value before assigning it to the array:

`$Polish_Dinner = $_POST['Pol_Desser'];`

Or, just assign the array index the appropriate value:

`$order[$i] = $_POST['Pol_Desser'];`

To carry the variable across multiple submissions, assign as a session variable.

IF, you can't use a SESSION Variable, then you could use $_GET, but this is not recommended as good practice.

Comment: wont help, he re-submits the page on every selection

Comment: That would be great but I cant do it - I have to compare result ('Pol_Desser') with my variable stored $Polish_Desser and then "put" it into the table.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. If you're limited to using nothing more than this, then Session is going to be your best friend with this. Then just kill the session when you're done.

Comment: Idiots never discover what we're talking about, nor would you be smart enough to get on SO and ask. So don't discourage yourself with such words. I get off work in 4 mins, but when I get home, I'll post you some resources so you can become more knowledgeable with PHP/Sessions/etc.. Everything worth doing is worth doing poorly until you learn to do it great.

Comment: Haha thanks -you are awsome guys! Ok I'll go google for it. Thanks for your help, I'll post my result when I'm done.

Answer (score 0):

I have some example code which may be useful but it is too long to share directly on here. I have put it here:

http://tny.cz/c681c8c9

I encountered a similar problem previously and really found this helpful. Unfortunately I can't find the original link to the site it was shared on. Let me know if you need any explanation of it

**UPDATE**

```
  $store = Array().         
  $order = **what you want to store**
  array_push($store, $order);
  $_SESSION['array'] = $store;
```

Then you can access the contents of the array in another area

Comment: Ok i start to get it but i still have blind point.
I've started session with session_start() ,then i made 
$i=0;
    $order[10]=new Dish;
    $_SESSION['order']=$order;
    $_SESSION['i']=$i;

Which means i store data from this variables on server and it's fine.Now should I replace every 
$order[$i]=$Mexican_Desser;
    $i++;
with
$_SESSION['order']=$Mexican_Desser;
$SESSION['i']++;
It can't be done like this - I dont increase i so it will be overwrite (it doesnt store even 1 value)

Comment: Dont increment the session directly. Have $i = 1, $i++, $SESSION[$i]. You could store it in an array of orders, ill update the answer above

Comment: Sory guys , i give up. Didnt sleep for 2 days and i barerly can see on my eyes. It can't be done.

surrender - topic can be deleted.

Comment: Sorry to hear, we all have these days, as a student I can only empathise too well... good luck :)